# Plugin that integrates Google Storage with WordPress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, cdn

[W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) and [CDN Sync Tool](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cdn-sync-tool/) (w/ WP Super Cache) are two plugins that do a pretty good job of integrating various Content Delivery Networks (CDN's) — including Amazon S3 / CloudFront, CloudFiles, and MaxCDN (among others) — with WordPress.

But I am looking for a plugin (free or paid) that integrates [Google Storage](http://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage.html) (not to be confused with Google Drive or others — [see pricing](http://cloud.google.com/pricing/cloud-storage.html)) with WordPress, and so far, could find none.

Has any come across a plugin that does this, by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WP2Cloud](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud/) plugin now supports Google Cloud Storage (in addition to Amazon S3).

Comment: This is the solution now https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/

Answer (score 2):

I found this one from the wordpress.org user jcnetsys in this topic: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-google-storage-compatibility

In the plugin-description:

> Very much WIP at the moment but I've uploaded my plugin (link below).
>    You'll need to have a google storage account (signup is free) and have
>    created a bucket.
>
> Open index.php and set the bucket and site name on lines 16 and 17 and
>    then fill in your access keys on line 47 which you can find out from
>    here:
>
> https://sandbox.google.com/storage/m/manage
>
> The site name allows you to have multiple sites delivered from the
>   same bucket.
>
> http://sandbox.google.com/storage/development_trunk/google-storage-cdn.zip

*Also note that you may have to wait for a few minutes after activating the plugin for all theme files and uploads to be transferred to google storage. The upload happens silently all the time that a user is logged in to the admin panel or alternatively you can go to the google storage page to see what is being uploaded.*

Comment: Actually, I did come across that. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Let alone, I don't know how secure the code is. I should've mentioned it in my question.

Comment: By the way, the right download link is: http://sandbox.google.com/storage/cdn-delivery/google-storage-cdn.zip